# Do tax professionals have a special phone number to get through to the IRS?

Tags: taxes, irs, tax-professionals

I have an ongoing audit since July 2022. I hired a tax professional to take care of the audit as I was not able to get a person on the phone when I tried calling many times. It's now almost July 2023.

I complained to the owner of the CPA firm that it's taking a long time and the CPA assigned to me forgot about my case. The owner apologized and assigned someone else to handle it. He acknowledged to me that all this time, no one on their end has gotten through to a human to speak with.

I asked them if there is a special phone number for tax professionals where the IRS will answer them (that is what a friend told me when they needed to get something done). The CPA said that there is no such thing and the CPA's try calling the same numbers as I have which is on the cover page of the notices sent to me.

Is this true? Tax professionals do not have a way to speak to someone aside from the same numbers that a regular person has?

Comment: If such a number existed, what would ensure that only "tax professionals" used it instead of the general public?

Comment: @brhans As noted in the answer below, this is restricted through evidence of the professional's practitioner number logged with the IRS, the PTIN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [they do](https://www.irs.gov/tax-professionals/practitioner-priority-service-r). You need a PTIN to call it, and a power of attorney from your client filed with the IRS. If you don't have these they will not talk to you.

---

That said, since in your case you're already under audit (at least that's what I remember from your previous questions), the specific phone number to call will indeed be listed on the notices, and the PPS line will probably not be able to help.

Comment: I presume getting a PTIN is a PITA?

Comment: @keshlam there's a fee, and some legal obligations that come with it, including being in public records as a paid tax preparer.

Answer (score 3):

The IRS has the [Taxpayer Advocate Service](https://www.irs.gov/taxpayer-advocate) that you can contact if things have stalled with the IRS. However, that will generally only be an option if the issue isn't being resolved according to normal procedures or if they're violating the [Taxpayer Bill of Rights](https://www.irs.gov/taxpayer-bill-of-rights).

It's possible that the IRS is extremely backed up and the CPA firm you've engaged really hasn't been able to get hold of an agent since they reassigned your case to someone who didn't forget about you. You might be able to work with TAS in that case. But if it's the CPA firm continually dropping the ball and giving you the runaround, you'll probably have no luck with TAS.